# Indicating range of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get all active records by quarter from 2016 to 2019 (given start and end dates)
The approach I'm trying to use is adding columns for each quarter, 1 will indicate active, 0 will indicate inactive.

In the attached sample image, you can see the results I am trying to get.
Record 1 was active only in Q1-2016, so it will have 0 for the other quarters.
Record 5 active starting Q4-2016 until Q4-2017.
Record 8 active all periods. (00/00/0000 represents currently active)

[image]

The formula I was using only shows they are active during the end_date quarter. 
For example for record 5, H9 is shown as active, but G9 should also be 1. They formula I am currently using shows it as 0.
All the 1's marked in blue are captured by the formula.
This formula does not work for active records (8 to 10)

How could I approach this? If you have a different approach to what I am trying to achieve (getting active records by quarter), please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the start dates of the quarters in the row above and use those as reference(you can make the text white to hide the values).  Then use this formula in E5, copy over and down.

```
=--(SUMPRODUCT((ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,E$3):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,IF(F$3="",EDATE(E$3,3),F$3)))>=$C5)*(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,E$3):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,IF(F$3="",EDATE(E$3,3),F$3)))<=$D5))>0)
```

It iterates the days in the quarter and checks if any days are in the date range.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you. I would have never thought about that.
What does $ZZ:$ZZ do?

Comment: @Poskaz it is a counter. It returns an array of numbers from the first date to the next date by using the row numbers as dates.  I chose column ZZ arbitrarily to minimize the recalcs.  If we used a column that routinely has their data changed it would force a recalc when one is not needed.